# laravel 6.x : change site title language using localisation

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an application which supports 2 different languages English and Arabic.
and i'm using this package: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization .

but i have this problem !

**Undefined property: stdClass::$site_meta_title_ (View: C:...**

**index.blade.php**

```
<title>{{ $config->site_meta_title_ . LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() }}</title>
```

**DB: table: config:**

[site_meta_title_en and site_meta_title_ar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFt06.png)

any help will be highly appreciated.

laravel 6.x

Comment: Post the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't used that package before, but I think you need to try like this:

```
<title>{{ $config->{'site_meta_title_' . LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()} }}</title>
```

As you've used property of $config instance dynamically, so you need to use like:

**$object->{'string_property_name'}**